# Gnome Applications menu doesn't reveal locations of apps

Tags: rhel

I've tried to use the following command, but it is missing the available applications listed in the Applications menu of the Gnome GUI/Desktop environment. I am not sure how to access the information for how these apps are being launched. In KDE or RHEL 6 Gnome (Gnome 2.x), it was easy to just right click on the application launcher and see the command it was using to launch the application. However with Gnome 3 on RHEL 8 I have had no such luck.

```
rpm -qa
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the path under /usr/local/share/applications. That is where the bulk of the applications are found in the Gnome applications menu.

@danielegrassini answered my question by pointing me to the following link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/747118/where-is-the-location-of-application-shortcuts-in-gnome.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for `Exec` keyword in the `application.desktop`.

`Gnome` keep `desktop entry` in `/usr/share/applications` each file, with the `.desktop` extension have a Keyword: `Exec`.

This hold the path to the executable been launched when an application is open.

As an example the `desktop entry` for my `thunderbird` says:

`Exec=/usr/bin/thunderbird %u`

Comment: I went to /usr/share/applications and there are many applications under this folder, but not all of the applications that are listed when I type in the search bar (hot key >> Type to search...). How is Gnome searching for the available applications that are returned using this search?

Comment: searching in the other directories there. see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747118/where-is-the-location-of-application-shortcuts-in-gnome) if help